# TCP packets merged at network level

Tags: java, networking, tcp, tcpdump

Does anybody knows how and why a counter party would receive TCP packets merged instead of individually packages? I already set TCP Nodelay to true at socket level, but tcpdump still sees some packets as merged.
After 4 successful packets sent with size of 310 bytes, I got 3 x 1400 bytes instead of 15 x 310 bytes. This is causing some important latency. Thanks.

http://www.2shared.com/photo/_bN9UEqR/tcpdump2.html

```
s = new Socket(host, port);
s.setTcpNoDelay(true);
s.getOutputStream().write(byteMsg); 
s.getOutputStream().flush()
```

Comment: How do you create the "packets"? Please post some code. BTW: TCP is a stream based protocol. You can never rely on the size of a transferred bunch of data. If you need separate packets use UDP.

Comment: Hi, I just write a message on the Socket, and expect the message to be sent without any delay. The application is trying to write multiple messages and to be sent in same order, as fast as possible.  s.getOutputStream().write(byteMsg);         s.getOutputStream().flush();

Answer (score 6):

TCP is a stream-based protocol. It doesn't preserve boundaries with respect to `send`/`recv` calls. The only thing guaranteed is that the concatenation of `send`'s will be the same as the concatenation of `recv`'s (under normal circumstances).

If you're implementing a custom protocol and need some way to split the data into multiple logical *messages*, you need an encoding for that.

A simple encoding is to encode each message as a 32-bit unsigned integer denoting the length of the message payload, followed by the actual message payload. Then, on the receiving side, properly decode the input according to this encoding. To do that, you will need a buffer that will store a partially received message. If manipulating raw integers is a problem, you can encode the length some other way, e.g. as a decimal number followed by a newline.

Comment: Does it mean that one call to `recv()` could retrieve the content of two `send()`?

Answer (score 3):

Coalescing can occur in many places

- sender application buffering
- sender OS buffering
- sender network adapter buffers
- router buffers
- receiver network adapter buffers
- receiver OS buffering
- receiver application buffers/queues

It appears from what you have said there is coalescing between the senders network adapter and the receiver's OS. (As tcp-no-delay instructs the OS not to buffer and tcpdump reads before the application)

Comment: Hi Peter, that's what I thought but not sure how I can identify the exact cause, and fix it. The TCP dump is the same on both client-server side, meaning we see big packets on both sides. My initial idea was that the problem is on router level, do you know how to capture this? Thanks.

Comment: if you see the problem on the sender side the problem is there. You could look at disabling nagle/coalescing in the OS or the network adapter.

Comment: @CristiL You *can't* 'fix it'. It isn't broken. What is broken is *your code,* if it has incorrect expectations about message boundaries in TCP. *That* is what you need to fix.

Comment: Its not clear to me whether this is a problem because a) your protocol expects "packets" to arrive the same way they were sent, which clearly never going to work reliably or b) its a sign of a latency in your system which is causing a business problem e.g. a trading system losing money.

Comment: @EJP, thanks for your explanation, I was not aware this is a TCP protocol limitation. Already tried to set TCPNoDelay to True, that helped allot but still see this kind of behavior.

Comment: @PeterLawrey a) its a regular TCP connection, and its a standard used by many counter parties, that means we can not change it. We only expect messages to be sent as fast as possible. The problem is actually b) since the messages are merged, each message has a undesired latency, that is causing serious issues on server side

Comment: You may be able to tune the network adapter configuration, or use a kernel by pass network adapter to reduce latency. e.g. http://www.openonload.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can try to enable the TCP_NODELAY option on the used socket (`setTcpNoDelay()` method).

It is by default disabled which means that the transmitted data is optimized for a minimum number of packages sent (see [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm)).

Comment: Thanks, already did that. It helped, but I still have the problem in some rare cases.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anybody knows how and why a counter party would receive TCP packages merged instead of individually packages?

Because that is what TCP is specifically designed to do.

Comment: and there's no way in forcing not do this? TCPNoDelay was an option, but is not 100% working.