# Why Socket over Tcp doesn't send if I call it too much in a millisecond?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sockets, tcp

I'm using following code

```
for(int i =0; i < 100; i++){ 
    TcpSocket.Send(getModifiedData(MyData));
}
```

The code is called too much, maybe one time per every tick.

The socket is connected to my local machine(127.0.0.1) so there is no latency, pocket loss etc.
The first messages are just fine but I don't get some pockets later.

Now if I change that code to following then all my pockets are sent and recieved!

```
for(int i =0; i < 100; i++){ 
    Console.WriteLine("SendData > " + TcpSocket.Send(getModifiedData(MyData)));
}
```

And yes I'm pretty sure because I have tested this more than 10 times. Logging to console with `WriteLine` method fixes this issue.

I'm totally lost with this very weird problem.

Note that following code helps to send more pockets than first default code posted in question.

```
for(int i =0; i < 100; i++){ 
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
    TcpSocket.Send(getModifiedData(MyData));
}
```

But even with sleeping about 10% of my pockets are lost!

I found logging to console best solution which sends 100% of pockets without loss.

Receiver code :

```
 // variables
    static NetworkStream^ NS;
 // CClient::NS = gcnew NetworkStream(CClient::sender);

//
Dictionary<String^, Object^>^ x = (Dictionary<String^, Object^>^)PClientFuncs::Deserialize(CClient::NS); 

//method
Object^ PClientFuncs::Deserialize(Stream^ s){
try{
    BinaryFormatter^ formatter = gcnew BinaryFormatter();
    DeflateStream^ serializationstream = gcnew DeflateStream(s, CompressionMode::Decompress);
    return formatter->Deserialize(serializationstream);


}
catch (Exception^) {
    return nullptr;
}
}
```

So What's the problem ? Why this happening and how to fix it ?

Comment: Please include the receive code: there is nothing you've said that eliminates the receiver as the root cause (or that suggests it is).

Comment: Can you show your receiving code as well.

Comment: @Richard The pockets are not even sent! I don't get what's the point of receiver code, However if this is necessary I'll attach it in a few minutes ?

Comment: @MattWilko It's okay I'll attach in a few minutes

Comment: What is TcpSocket? I don't know of any such class.

Comment: @usr Sorry I meant Socket over Tcp. I'll edit question right now!

Comment: On further thought I think, from the description we're going to need two things (1) how do you know you are getting packet loss, (2) a complete working re-create (ie. a pair of short programs that demonstrate the issue).

Comment: @Richard I'm logging every single pocket as soon as received then it's sent to processing. I'll attach a part of receiver code but don't know if you can re-create this problem. I'll try to add a short code

Comment: That "receive code" does nothing with sockets: it does not show how you are receiving data (only that you are decompressing/deserialising at some later point). Please expand to a minimal working demonstration.

Comment: @Richard Thank you! I have added more!. I'll provide a minimal working demonstration soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that TCP sends data in packets. This is not true. [TCP presents you a contiguous stream of bytes.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11242619/122718) This means that what you receive is not necessarily received in the same "chunks" as you send it. Probably, that is confusing your receiver.

The best way to deal with this is to not write a TCP-based application. Use some higher-level construct like HTTP. Libraries for clients and servers are available. They solve a lot of problems for you.

Comment: Yes! I guess you are right however I'll wait for other answers too. Thanks!

Comment: Anyway why logging to console fix the issue ? do you know ?

Comment: This probably slowed it down. The console is very slow on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it

```
for(int i =0; i < 100; i++){ 
Console.WriteLine("SendData > " + TcpSocket.Send(getModifiedData(MyData)));
```

}

and it's working just fine. http://prntscr.com/mfswpr

Can you show us your client and server socket?

Comment: 100 packet fully received.

Answer (score -2):

My best guess is that your receiving code is to slow, and TCP buffer simply overflows.

If you generate data faster than you can process it, some of it will eventually get lost.

Comment: TCP never loses data. Buffering is an implementation detail.