# Node js TCP data

Tags: node.js

When receiving data on a TCP socket in Node.js, will the `data` variable *always* contain an entire TCP message? IE is there every any reason to buffer the data? Do I need to check for start/end delimiters, or encapsulate in a custom protocol with header? So far it looks like everything always comes perfectly packaged, but this is a local environment.

```
this.server = net.createServer((socket) => {
    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}).listen(this.port);
```

Comment: Try sending a string longer than 10kb without newlines and you will find `console.log` inserting some newlines not in the original string because the string was split into several TCP messages

Comment: Then what exactly is "data"? How did Node put this data together?

Comment: `data` is the payload from the TCP packet. Node gets it form the device driver running on your OS which gets it from your network card (or in the case of loopback device like 127.0.0.1 from RAM)

Comment: It is not node's fault that packets larger than 10kb may be split in 2. That's just how TCP/IP was designed

Comment: Note that this can also happen in reverse. Two smaller packets can potentially arrive in a single packet. See this Java question for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241430/tcp-packets-merged-at-network-level. It's not related to what language you're using. It's how networking was designed.

Comment: So If I send "Hello World" can I potentially get "Hel", "low ", "World" as three packets? If I sent it twice might I get the end of the intended previous message as part of the first? IE "World Hel" "low World"?

Comment: Yes. Think of TCP as more like a keyboard than letters in envelopes

Comment: So even in TCP, you always need your own encapsulation/envelope?

Comment: Yes. That's why there are protocols such as HTTP, Bittorrent, FTP etc. The good news is that node.js comes with a HTTP library built in so you don't need to invent your own if you don't want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** Will the data variable always contain an entire TCP message?

**A:** Not always.

**Q:** Do I need to check for start/end delimiters, or encapsulate in a custom protocol with header?

**A:** Depends. If the sender is not going to `end` the socket after sending is done then you will need a method to signify the start and end of a message.

Answer (score 2):

This is not node.js specific but related to TCP/IP.

There is no guarantee that a single TCP packet contains an entire message - in any language. TCP/IP includes such features as [packet fragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_fragmentation) where your OS or network card or router or modem or your ISP's router or the router of the other machine's ISP or any router in between or the other machine may split your packet into two or more packets.

TCP specifically is not packet oriented, it is stream oriented. The only thing TCP guarantees is that the order of bytes in the received message is the same as the transmitted message. That means that if you send `Hello World` the other side will receive `Hello World` instead of `HloeWlr odl`. Think of TCP as sort of a networked keyboard protocol instead of a message sending protocol.

It is for this reason that TCP is not used as a high level protocol to send data. Usually you would encapsulate data in another higher level protocol such as HTTP or FTP or even JSON to detect start and end of message.